# Submit to app store as lite version and full version

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having two separate apps like "Lite version" and "Full version", with two different provisioning. I want to submit these two apps in apple store. How to do that ?

Please anyone help to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create 2 different app ids on the provisioning portal with 2 different bundle identifiers and upload them to itunes connect as 2 different apps.

But the best thing you can do is use only one free version and unlock the "Full version" with an In App Purchase that changes a boolean (ej:`boughtFullVersion`), and check that boolean on the "Full version" features, to make them only work if the "Full version" was purchased

Comment: @downvoter please leave reason for downvote then user has the chance to correct, amend or improve there answer. Leaving a reason benefits everyone.

Comment: I think it's because I gave an answer for using just one version and he has 2 separate versions. I've updated my answer with some info about how to have 2 separate versions. Anyways, the thread is closed.

Comment: sorry,please can you throw more information on lite and full versions app submitting.

Comment: But do you know how to upload a single app? It's like submiting 2 different apps

Answer (score 1):

You can just submit them as 2 different apps, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the apple tutorial to submit apps to app store. Please follow the guide to upload your apps.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html

Comment: @Popeye, Can you pleased read the question again and understand whats the context. It is about submitting apps to appstore.

Comment: Well ever way the downvote from me was for not providing the a summary of the section you mean in the article. As links can expire so this answer could be completely useless. I did ask for where you meant and you decided not to do so, so I think that this deserved a downvote because of that. If you decide to update your answer with this summary I will remove my downvote.